# Insert new rows if values from TWO columns doens't already exists (peewee with PostgreSQL db)

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I'm trying to insert new rows if values from `user_id` AND `answered_at` doesn't already exists in my table.

Here's my model:

```
class NPS(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        schema = os.getenv('SCHEMANAME')
        table_name = os.getenv('TABLENAME')

    user_id = pw.IntegerField()
    answered_at = pw.DateField()
    score = pw.IntegerField()
    motivation = pw.TextField()
    comment = pw.TextField(null=True)
    attempts = pw.DateField()
    scores = pw.TextField()
```

And here's the insert part, where `dados_nps` is a list of dicts in right format:

```
cursor = (NPS
          .insert_many(dados_nps)
          .on_conflict(conflict_target=[NPS.user_id, NPS.answered_at], action='ignore')
          .returning())

inserted_rows = cursor.execute()
print(inserted_rows)
```

As you can see, I'm passing a list of (two) fields in `conflict_target`: `[NPS.user_id, NPS.answered_at]`. But this is not working, because the rows are always inserted.
The `action` argument is right? There's something else I'm missing in my class model definition or inside the `on_conflict()` method?

Maybe should I set something in `constrainst` using `Check()` like this example?

```
class Meta:
   constraints = [Check('user_id AND answered_at NOT EXISTS')]
```

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html?highlight=constraint#indexes-and-constraints

Obs: I'm using `returning()` to after this count the number of rows inserted.

Comment: ON CONFLICT requires a unique index. I'm not familiar with peewee, but [based on this](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html?highlight=constraint#multi-column-indexes), try adding `indexes = ((('user_id', 'answered_at'), True),)` to `Meta`.

Answer (score 0):

As @AdamKG pointed out, I needed to pass unique indexes to my class model.
This solves the problem, thanks!

If someone else is still getting this problem, maybe this can be the error:

I was trying to do this, but not working yet

```
class NPS(BaseModel):

    user_id = pw.IntegerField()
    answered_at = pw.DateField()
    score = pw.IntegerField()
    motivation = pw.TextField()
    comment = pw.TextField(null=True)
    attempts = pw.DateField()
    scores = pw.TextField()

    class Meta:
        schema = os.getenv('SCHEMANAME')
        table_name = os.getenv('TABLENAME')

        indexes = (
            (('user_id', 'answered_at'), True)
        )
```

But the documentation says that we need to keep the trailing comma in the 2-tuple, so this works:

```
class NPS(BaseModel):

    user_id = pw.IntegerField()
    answered_at = pw.DateField()
    score = pw.IntegerField()
    motivation = pw.TextField()
    comment = pw.TextField(null=True)
    attempts = pw.DateField()
    scores = pw.TextField()

    class Meta:
        schema = os.getenv('SCHEMANAME')
        table_name = os.getenv('TABLENAME')

        # need to keep the trailing comma
        indexes = (
            (('user_id', 'answered_at'), True),
        )
```

Note the trailing coma in `indexes`.